# In SymPy, why does the summing of 2 random variables yield inscrutable result?

Tags: python, statistics, sympy

Considering the summation of 2 Gaussian variables in SymPy:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import *

init_printing()

a = Normal('a', 0, Symbol('P', real=true))
b = Normal('b', 0, Symbol('Q', real=true))

ss = a + b

pprint(simplify(density(ss)))
```

I would expect the result to be a PDF of a gaussian with more variance. Instead the result looks like this:

```
    ⎧    ⎛               2  2                                                 
    ⎪    ⎜              z ⋅P                                                  
    ⎪    ⎜         ───────────────                                            
    ⎪    ⎜              ⎛  2     ⎞                                            
    ⎪    ⎜            4 ⎜ P     1⎟                                            
    ⎪    ⎜         4⋅Q ⋅⎜──── + ─⎟                                            
    ⎪    ⎜              ⎜   2   2⎟                                           2
    ⎪    ⎜              ⎝2⋅Q     ⎠    ⎛         z⋅P         ⎞               z 
    ⎪    ⎜  z⋅π⋅P⋅ℯ               ⋅erf⎜─────────────────────⎟          ───────
    ⎪    ⎜                            ⎜           __________⎟               ⎛ 
    ⎪    ⎜                            ⎜          ╱   2      ⎟             4 ⎜ 
    ⎪    ⎜                            ⎜   2     ╱   P     1 ⎟          4⋅Q ⋅⎜─
    ⎪    ⎜                            ⎜2⋅Q ⋅   ╱   ──── + ─ ⎟               ⎜ 
    ⎪    ⎜                            ⎜       ╱       2   2 ⎟               ⎝2
    ⎪    ⎜                            ⎝     ╲╱     2⋅Q      ⎠   z⋅π⋅P⋅ℯ       
    ⎪  Q⋅⎜- ───────────────────────────────────────────────── - ──────────────
    ⎪    ⎜                           __________                            ___
    ⎪    ⎜                          ╱   2                                 ╱   
    ⎪    ⎜                   2     ╱   P     1                     2     ╱   P
z ↦ ⎨    ⎜                2⋅Q ⋅   ╱   ──── + ─                  2⋅Q ⋅   ╱   ──
    ⎪    ⎜                       ╱       2   2                         ╱      
    ⎪    ⎝                     ╲╱     2⋅Q                            ╲╱     2⋅
    ⎪- ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    ⎪                                             3/2                         
    ⎪                                        2⋅z⋅π   ⋅P                       
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎪                                                                         
    ⎩                                                                         
... (426 lines in total)                                         

                         ⎞                                             ⎞
 ⎛      1          ⎞│   π⎟   │                 ⎛      1          ⎞│   π⎟
t⎜──────────────, ∞⎟│ < ─⎟ ∨ │periodic_argument⎜──────────────, ∞⎟│ < ─⎟
 ⎜          2      ⎟│   2⎟   │                 ⎜          2      ⎟│   2⎟
 ⎝polar_lift (P)   ⎠│    ⎠   │                 ⎝polar_lift (P)   ⎠│    ⎠
```

Why SymPy gave such a strange result and what should I do to get the succinct form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the second parameter (standard deviation, "sigma") as positive:

```
a = Normal('a', 0, Symbol('P', positive=True))
b = Normal('b', 0, Symbol('Q', positive=True))
```

Then the result is as expected:

```
               2     
             -z      
         ─────────── 
            2      2 
         2⋅P  + 2⋅Q  
     √2⋅ℯ            
z ↦ ─────────────────
            _________
           ╱  2    2 
    2⋅√π⋅╲╱  P  + Q
```

Under the hood, SymPy calculates an improper integral using Meijer G function, which involves lifting the computation to some Riemann surface, and having negative numbers for P or Q can result in taking another branch; hence the complicated answer. Mathematically, this should not matter much for the computation, since the sigma is squared in the exponent; but it matters for the success of the algorithm.

All this would be moot if SymPy just knew how the independent normals get added, but it does not; all such computations are done by direct integration, often stretching the limits of the implemented integration methods.

Remarks:

1. You have used `true` (SymPy truth object), but Python's `True` is expected by symbol creation method.
2. It's best to avoid combining `from sympy import *` and `from sympy.stats import *` because this results in naming conflicts: `E` is Euler's number in SymPy *and* the notation of expected value in sympy.stats.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a big oversight.